# How to subtract sale table from purchase table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: **sale** and **purchase** connected via `SarialNo=Sarial_Num`

```
sale: (SDate,SarialNo,Cname,Caddress,Itemname,Itemgroup,Price,Qty,TotalAmount) 
purchase: (Sarial_Num,dealerid,Pdate,Itemgroup,Itemname,description,Price,Qty,totalamount)
```

now I want to subtract (Price,Qty,TotalAmount) of sale table from (Price,Qty,TotalAmount) of purchase and group by them by SarialNo, Sarial_Num

Comment: SarialNo, Sarial_Num are same

Comment: Cool - what have you tried?

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected results? I'm not sure what you're looking for. Do you want three columns, (t1.price - t2.price as totalPrice), (t1.quantity - t2.quantity as totalQuantity) ?

Comment: The downvotes are likely because you are asking a broad question that is a little unclear. I suggest reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how you can improve your question, because there may be a really interesting question behind all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from scratch you may have been able to easily find this answer somewhere on the internet.

```
SELECT (p.Price - s.Price) PriceDiff, 
       (p.Qty - s.Qty) QtyDiff, 
       (p.TotalAmount - s.TotalAmount) TotalDiff
FROM Purchase p JOIN Sale s
       ON p.Sarial_Num = s.SarialNo
GROUP BY s.SarialNo, p.Sarial_Num
```

This is assuming you have data types set up correctly as well as relationships.